# Context menu for multiple selected items in custom tree view in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Custom tree views in VSCode API can now be configured with [canSelectMany](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeViewOptions), but how does one configure context menus and commands for multiple selected items?

When I set my tree view's `canSelectMany` to `true`, I can select multiple items but when I right-click them, I still see the same context menu as if I just right-clicked a single item. Is there any way I can configure a different context menu when multiple items are selected? And is there a way to run a command from the context menu with a list of all the selected items?

Comment: I believe that you add the context menu option under `view/item/context`. What's the `when` you're using?

Comment: Yes, I have the context menu defined already under `view/item/context`, with the `when` clause looking something like this: `view == dataManagementView && viewItem == bucket`. What I'm wondering is, can you somehow configure the `view/item/context` menu items so that they are shown/hidden based on whether there are multiple items selected?

Comment: You can try with `listDoubleSelection` - https://github.com/moshfeu/vscode-compare-folders/blob/05e0df61c65f65113f6375a0b99773080c6ce0fb/package.json#L142

Comment: I tried `listDoubleSelection` as well as `listMultiSelection` but with no luck. I'm afraid these options are only available under `explorer/context` (as in your code), and not under `view/item/context`.

Comment: Interesting point. I haven't tried it by myself but I smell a feature request :)

Comment: Looks like there is a github issue already, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99767, although in that case they've been using the `enablement` property of the command itself.

Comment: For " is there a way to run a command from the context menu with a list of all the selected items?"  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70307717/836330

Comment: `"when": "viewItem == TreeTab && listMultiSelection`  works perfectly fine for me.  Looks like the issue has been fixed.