# How to get the Multi Selected files from the File Explorer in an extension command

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In `package.json` you can add a command to the File Explorer context menu.

In File Explorer you can select multiple files but my command only gets the last selected file URI as argument.

Can I get a list of all the selected files in the File Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at my extension [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview) to see how I parse multiple files when an explorer context menu command is triggered.  [There is some extra code in there because that command can be triggered by a keybinding or explorer/editor/tab menus so they have to be handled differently.]

```js
let contextMenuCommandFile = vscode.commands.registerCommand('find-and-transform.searchInFile', async (...commandArgs) => {

    let args = {};

    if (commandArgs?.length === 1 && !(commandArgs[0] instanceof vscode.Uri)) {   // if from keybinding
      let argsArray = Object.entries(commandArgs[0]).filter(arg => {
        return searchCommands.getKeys().includes(arg[0]);
      });
      Object.assign(args, Object.fromEntries(argsArray));
    }

    args.filesToInclude = await parseCommands.parseArgs(commandArgs, "file");
    args.triggerSearch = true;
        searchCommands.useSearchPanel(args);
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(contextMenuCommandFile);
```

You might be missing this `async (...commandArgs) => {` to get all available passed arguments into an array.

`...commandArgs` will be of length 1 if coming from a keybinding and length 2 if trigggered from the context menu **no matter** how many files were selected in the Explorer before right-clicking on one and choosing the command.

`commandArgs[0]` is the single file (i.e., the last file) on which I right-clicked.
`commandsArgs[1]` is itself an array of all the selected files in the explorer.

I then send that `commandArgs` array to be parsed (since I just need a comma-separated list of the files selected) to `parseCommands.parseArgs()` [okay, strangely-named function!).

The operative bit there is:

```js
    else if (commandArgs[1][0] instanceof vscode.Uri) {              // explorer/context
      for (const resource of commandArgs[1]) {
        const thisResource = vscode.workspace.asRelativePath(resource.fsPath);
        resources += `${ thisResource }, `;
      }
      resources = resources.substring(0, resources.length - 2);  // strip ', ' off end
      return resources;
    }
```

[image: multiple files selected in explorer menu]

---

It would probably be better to use:

```js
vscode.commands.registerCommand('find-and-transform.searchInFile', async (contextSelection: vscode.Uri, allSelections: vscode.Uri[]) => {
```

which splits the `...commandArgs` from above into its constituent parts: the item right-clicked on `contextSelection` and the array of all selections `allSelections`.  Then you don't need notation like `commandArgs[1]` to refer to all the selections but could use the simpler `allSelections`.

Thanks to @PeterWone at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75533230/836330.

Comment: Ah, that pesky `...`, I program to much Python, you can simply the result string: `return commandArgs[1].map(r => vscode.workspace.asRelativePath(r.fsPath)).join(', ');`