# VSCode API Extension get URI of context menu

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, contextmenu, vscode-extensions

I am building a `VSCode-Extension` and I managed to call my `function` via 'right-click' on the files.

This is my `package.json`:

```
  "main": "./extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [{
      "command": "flutter-localization-generator.create",
      "title": "localize_it: create"
    }],
    "menus": {
      "explorer/context": [{
          "command": "flutter-localization-generator.create"
    }]
  }
```

The thing is that I need the `URI` from where the user clicked on the `method`. Is that possible? How do I access it inside the `activate`?

```
function activate(context) {

    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "flutter-localization-generator" is now active!');

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('flutter-localization-generator.create', function () {


        console.log(context.globalStorageUri);
        console.log(context.extensionUri);

        console.log(context.extensionPath);
        console.log(context.rootPath);

    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
```

I tried different of things but all of the above `logs` do not get me the desired `path`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which file or files were selected and right-clicked will be passed to your context menu command, see more at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/70307717/836330.

Add `args` (any name you want) to your command callback - the information you want will automatically be passed as arguments there.

```js
let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('flutter-localization-generator.create', function (...args) {
```

Then `args` will be an array containing in `[0]` the file that was right-clicked on, and in `[1]` all the files that might have been selected when one of them was right-clicked and your context menu function selected and run.