# How to obtain a list of selected files from the explorer pane of VS Code?

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

You can set up a multiple selection in the VS Code explorer pane. Right-clicking on the selection fires a context menu and as you can see in the screen capture I have contributed a Print item to this menu.

[image]

The menu item contribution binds it to a command.

```json
        "menus": {
            "explorer/context": [
                {
                    "command": "vsc-print.print",
                    "group": "navigation"
                }
            ],
```

Activation registers the command.

```js
    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand("vsc-print.print", printCommand));
```

When the command executes this is called.

```js
function printCommand(cmdArgs: any): PrintSession {
    logger.debug("Print command was invoked");
    const printSession = new PrintSession(cmdArgs, false);
    printSessions.set(printSession.sessionId, printSession);
    return printSession;
}
```

Contrary to expectation, `cmdArgs` is *not* an array of `vscode.Uri`. All you get is the `vscode.Uri` for the file under the right-click, highlighted by a blue border in the illustration above.

Documentation describes only the contribution of additional view containers. There is no mention of how to get my hooks into baked-in stuff. Can anyone tell me how to get the list of selected files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to get the Multi Selected files from the File Explorer in an extension command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70307717/836330) for more.  Adding an answer here mainly for the typescript addition.

Try this:

```js
function printCommand(...cmdArgs: [vscode.Uri, vscode.Uri[]]): PrintSession {

// or

function printCommand(contextSelection: vscode.Uri, allSelections: vscode.Uri[]): PrintSession {
```

Using the spread operator `...` will cause the `cmdArgs` to collect all passed arguments into an unusual array of the Explorer item you right-clicked on and all the files that were highlighted - including the file in the first array position.

Upon further examination @PeterWone indicated that the first version `...cmdArgs` can be resolved to the second version `contextSelection: vscode.Uri, allSelections: vscode.Uri[]`.

I gave them those names in an attempt to explain what they are.  The first argument `contextSelection` is the file, actually the `vscode.Uri`, that you right-clicked on to bring up the context menu where your extension command is located.

The second argument `allSelections` is an array of `vscode.Uri`'s that does include the item you right-clicked on and any other files that might have been selected at the time.  Interestingly, there does appear to be a specific order to that array.  It is in the order of the selections made - so the first item in the array could be below or above the next file selected in the Explorer.  The first item selected will appear first in the `allSelections` array, and so on.  I don't know how often that the order will typically be of much use to the extension author...

In my testing it looks like `cmdArgs` will be typed as `[vscode.Uri, vscode.Uri[]]` if you care to move away from the `any`.

Comment: I figured this out and was coming back to write an answer, but you beat me to it. A signature of `(cmdArgs: vscode.Uri, multiselection: Array<vscode.Uri>)` also works. With the weird nomenclature he's chosen ("Multi Selected") I'm not surprised I didn't find that.

Comment: I'm going to add your findings to the answer, plus a little more I learned on testing.